# Why is json files not accessible after build?

Tags: reactjs

I have a project in react that works on the computer excellently.
But after I do build and upload it to the server all the json files in the public folder get a 404 error (even when I try to access them directly and click on the url I get the same error.)
But the icon and png files from the same folder do appear.

Another problem (which is probably also related) is that when I go through the link pages on the site it goes great. But if I type them directly in the url I get a 404 error message

I tried to add to json

```
     "homepage": ".", "
```

But even that did not help.

Anyone have an idea?

**edit:**
the json works .. I had to change the settings of the mime types according to the instructions: https: //docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/website-management/websites-and-domains/extended- website-management / using-virtual-directories-windows / adding-and-removing-mime-types.65216 /

But I was still left with the problem that when I go directly to the url address it makes me an error page (when the project is on the local host, it works fine!)

Regards,

Comment: Have you inspected the build folder and checked if the JSON files exist there?

Comment: Seems to be invalid JSON.